# Log VarDumper output to logs instead displaying it in prod environment

Tags: symfony, silex, monolog

Is there a bundle or some setting to log output of `dump()` function into logs file (probably with Monolog) instead of displaying it to user in PROD environment?

I know I can make my own handler with `VarDumper::setHandler()`, but I believe I'm not the first one with this idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full solution (for Silex):**

```php
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\VarCloner;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

$monologHandler = function($var) use ($app) {
    $cloner = new VarCloner();
    $dumper = new CliDumper();
    $output = '';

    $dumper->dump(
        $cloner->cloneVar($var), 
        function ($line, $depth) use (&$output) {
            // A negative depth means "end of dump"
            if ($depth >= 0) {
                // Adds a two spaces indentation to the line
                $output .= str_repeat('  ', $depth).$line."\n";
            }
        }
    );
    $app['monolog']->addNotice($output); //you can change this to addInfo, addDebug or what you prefer
};

VarDumper::setHandler($monologHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using setHandler is your answer. Do the following:

```
VarDumper::setHandler(function ($var) use ($app) {
    $cloner = new VarCloner();
    $dumper = 'cli' === PHP_SAPI ? new CliDumper() : new HtmlDumper();

    // you could call monolog here

    $dumper->dump($cloner->cloneVar($var));
});
```

I'm not quite sure why you would do this though. Monolog is for useful information during the application flow. dump is a poor man's debugging tool.

Comment: I use `dump()` instead of `var_dump()` in dev env to output some debug information, I would like to see this information in logs too.

Comment: Try the above then, although I disagree with this approach. You could make a dump2 command which called dump and also monolog... `function dump2($var) use ($app) { dump($var); $app['monolog']->addInfo(var_export($var, true)); }`

Comment: There are times where you're making AJAX calls and you can't `dump()` things to the site and need to see what's going on in the dev logs. Can't see the HTML when the page doesn't load and the DeveloperBar can't catch it either.